# How to split a matrix based on how close the values are?

Tags: matlab, matrix, split

Suppose I have a matrix `A`:

```
A = [1 2 3 6 7 8];
```

I would like to split this matrix into sub-matrices based on how relatively close the numbers are. For example, the above matrix must be split into:

```
B = [1 2 3];
C = [6 7 8];
```

I understand that I need to define some sort of criteria for this grouping so I thought I'd take the absolute difference of the number and its next one, and define a limit upto which a number is allowed to be in a group. But the problem is that I cannot fix a static limit on the difference since the matrices and sub-matrices will be changing.

Another example:

```
A = [5 11 6 4 4 3 12 30 33 32 12];
```

So, this must be split into:

```
B = [5 6 4 4 3];
C = [11 12 12];
D = [30 33 32];
```

Here, the matrix is split into three parts based on how close the values are. So the criteria for this matrix is different from the previous one though what I want out of each matrix is the same, to separate it based on the closeness of its numbers. Is there any way I can specify a general set of conditions to make the criteria dynamic rather than static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid, my answer comes too late for you, but maybe future readers with a similar problem can profit from it.

In general, your problem calls for [cluster analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis). Nevertheless, maybe there's a simpler solution to your actual problem. Here's my approach:

1. First, [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) the input `A`.
2. To find a criterion to distinguish between "intraclass" and "interclass" elements, I calculate the differences between adjacent elements of `A`, using [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html).
3. Then, I calculate the [`median`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/median.html) over all these differences.
4. Finally, I [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) the indices for all differences, which are greater or equal than three times the median, with a minimum difference of `1`. (Depending on the actual data, this might be modified, e.g. using `mean` instead.) These are the indices, where you will have to "split" the (sorted) input.
5. At last, I set up two vectors with the starting and end indices for each "sub-matrix", to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38502817/11089932) approach using [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to get a cell array with all desired "sub-matrices".

Now, here comes the code:

```matlab
% Sort input, and calculate differences between adjacent elements
AA = sort(A);
d = diff(AA);

% Calculate median over all differences
m = median(d);

% Find indices with "significantly higher difference", 
% e.g. greater or equal than three times the median
% (minimum difference should be 1)
idx = find(d >= max(1, 3 * m));

% Set up proper start and end indices
start_idx = [1 idx+1];
end_idx = [idx numel(A)];

% Generate cell array with desired vectors
out = arrayfun(@(x, y) AA(x:y), start_idx, end_idx, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Due to the unknown number of possible vectors, I can't think of way to "unpack" these to individual variables.

Some tests:

```
  A =
     1   2   3   6   7   8

  out =
  {
    [1,1] =
       1   2   3

    [1,2] =
       6   7   8
  }


  A =
      5   11    6    4    4    3   12   30   33   32   12

  out =
  {
    [1,1] =
       3   4   4   5   6

    [1,2] =
       11   12   12

    [1,3] =
       30   32   33
  }


  A =
     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   3   3   3

  out =
  {
    [1,1] =
       1   1   1   1   1   1   1

    [1,2] =
       2   2   2   2   2   2

    [1,3] =
       3   3   3   3   3   3   3
  }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've completed working on the problem but this helped me understand cluster analysis better, thank you for answering :)