# How to extract substrings with different lengths?

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

I have an `n by 2` matrix that contains start and end indices of substrings of a specified string. How can I extract the `n by 1` cell array of substrings without a for-loop?

```matlab
string = 'Hello World!';
ranges = [1 1;
    2 3;
    4 5;
    3 7];
substrings = cell(size(ranges, 1), 1);
for i=1:size(ranges, 1)
    substrings{i} = string(ranges(i, 1):ranges(i, 2));
end
```

The expected result:

> ```
> substrings = 
> 'H'
> 'el'
> 'lo'
> 'llo W'
> ```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501128/efficient-colon-operator-for-multiple-start-and-end-points) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429966/create-an-index-vector-based-on-start-and-stop-values) two related questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cellfun` to make it a single-line operation:

```matlab
str = 'Hello World!';
ranges = [  1 1;
            2 3;
            4 5;
            3 7];
% first convert "ranges" to a cell object
Cranges = mat2cell(ranges,ones(size(ranges,1),1),2);
% call "cellfun" on every row/entry of "Cranges"
cellfun(@(x)str(x(1):x(2)),Cranges, 'UniformOutput',false)
```

> ans =
>
> 4×1 cell array
>
> ```
> {'H'    }
> {'el'   }
> {'lo'   }
> {'llo W'}
> ```

I have changed the variable `string` to `str` because `string` is a native function in MATLAB (converting the input to the type *string*).

Although this is single-line operation, it doesn't mean that it is more efficient:

```matlab
Num = 1000000;
        
substrings = cell(size(ranges, 1), 1);
% time for-loop
tic
for j = 1:Num
    for i = 1:size(ranges, 1)
        substrings{i} = str(ranges(i, 1):ranges(i, 2));
    end
end
toc;

Cranges = mat2cell(ranges,ones(size(ranges,1),1),2);
% time function-call
tic
for j = 1:Num
    substrings = cellfun(@(x)str(x(1):x(2)),Cranges, 'UniformOutput',false);
end
toc;
```

> ```
> Elapsed time is 3.929622 seconds. 
> Elapsed time is 50.319609 seconds.
> ```